# How can I implement current source and turn theoretical schematic into schematic with real components?

Tags: schematic

I would like to know how can I build some circuit with current source drawn in the "middle of everything" on some theoretical schematic of amplifier or some other circuit.

For example I have choosen this simple schematic (Collpits generator):

[image]

Is this current source literally a source and provides energy, or this is just current limiter which I can build with LM117/LM317 and resistor like this:

[image]

EDIT:

Another example (current source in "in the middle of everything" - LT3083 regulator block diagram):

[image]

I realize that theoretical schematic contains ideal elements and I'm NOT asking about that. I want to know how to replace this with real components:

[image]

Comment: It's not just "in the middle", as one of it's terminals is grounded - in this case it's called a current sink. You can build one with an NPN transistor easily, with using voltage divider bias and an emitter resistor.

Comment: @Sasszem You are right. I have choosen too simple example. How about second schematic (that's block diagram of LT3083 regulator)?

Comment: Well, I think a similar structure is still possible, you just have to keep the voltage across the base and the other end of the emitter resistor constant, for example with a zener, and the current will be constant as well. I'm not so sure about the practicality of it however.

Comment: @Sasszem The trouble with that is stability over process/temperature/voltage. The usual way is a more complex precision current source which was copied using current mirrors everywhere it's needed -- I don't know if I have the time to write a full answer this exact second but I'll start on one when I get the chance.

Comment: @Kamil You don't replace ideal current sources while keeping the rest of the behavioral circuit. It's there, with the surrounding behavioral components, to *communicate* a specific conceptual mechanism. In your last case, it's communicating that **SET** allows a grounded resistor to set a voltage reference that an ideal opamp uses to then regulate an unregulated source with good current compliance. It sets out a conceptual approach, kind of like a patent does. How you implement it depends on re-imagination and situational specs. Not robotic lock-step rigid replacement of a behavioral diagram.